# How can I split a string with accents in PHP?

Tags: php, string, substr, non-ascii-characters

I would like to split hurgarian strings which have accents.
Now I use this code:

```
if(strlen($row['title'])<=20)
    {
        echo $row['title'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo substr($row['title'], 0, 17)." ...";
    }
```

I store these datas with latin2_hungarian_ci coding in the database and I use charset in php files. Both in PHP and HTML part:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

But with this way if the last character is a non english character (é,á,ö,ü,ó,ő,ú,ű,í) it isn't appears well. Against this character appears a � simbol.
If I don't use substr just write the whole tite out everíthing works good.

Now for example:
A végzet erekly� ... or Északi széless� ...

I can't understand this substr, because in my examples from one of them write 15 characters and that simbol, from the other one 16 characters and that simbol.

How can I write out the first x characters from all of them?

Comment: The problem isn't the substring it's the text in `$row['title']`. Make your database encoding `UTF-8` aswell.

Comment: Have a look to [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

Comment: I tried the utf-8 database encoding and the `mb_substr()`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with this way:

```
if(strlen($row['title'])<=20)
    {
        echo $row['title'];
    }
    else
    {
        $result = "";
        $alphas = range('A', 'Z');
        $last = substr($row['title'], 15, 16);
        $title = $row['title'];
        if($alphas != "%".$last."%")
        {
            for($i=0; $i<18; $i++) {
                $result .= $title[$i];
            }

        }
        else
        {
            for($i=0; $i<17; $i++) {
                $result .= $title[$i];
            }
        }
        echo $result." ...";
    }
```

Thank you everyone the helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.iconv.php) function to change charset from latin2 to utf-8 and then make `mb_substr`.

```
echo iconv("ISO-8859-2","UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $string);
```

Comment: I can't use `iconv()`, it writes it's undefined function. I tried `utf8_decode` but now every non english character wrong.

Comment: Do you have after connection establish execution of query `SET NAMES 'utf8'` which change charset of communication between db and application to utf8?

Comment: I tried with and without `SET NAMES 'utf8'`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Now I tried with this code:

```
function charfunction($myStr,$limit=17) {    
    $result = "";
    for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++) {
        $result .= $myStr[$i];
    }
    return $result;    
}
```

And write out:

```
echo charfunction($row['title'])." ...";
```

The full title in `$row['title']` is A végzet ereklyéi - Csontváros

If I use `$limit=17` it writes A végzet erekly� ...

If I change to `$limit=18` it writes A végzet ereklyé ...

Counts the � simbol for two characters. But the é character is in that position it appears �.
Why?